How to minimize tension with an advisor with strong personality
He always thinks he is right, specially when we talk together, sometimes I ask a question and he just became super angry and made me feel dumb.
That's why I try to minimize my interactions and meetings with him, I usually polish his raw ideas and when we set a meeting he says all my polishings are completely wrong.
Like today, he blamed me an entire hour because I am a grad student yet I don't know the difference between PSD kernel and PSD matrix. Though I am sure that I was right, he insisted on his words and I just have to give up every time, and after sometime, usually another grad student or Postdoc mention exactly the same point and he admit that.
Sometimes I think maybe I approach him in a wrong way but I'm sure this is not the case, I never tell him "YOU ARE WRONG IN ..." (though he is actually wrong), I just say something like "I didn't understand, could you please explain ..." hoping that he recognize his mistake, however, he starts insisting on that.
Honestly how can I just be clear to him and finish my MSc? I don't want to have any tension with him.
Like look at this which happened today:
Prove matrix constructed based on gaussian RBF is PSD
I used to thought that maybe I am the problem not him, but I hear the same stories from the students of his courses, they always say he made them feel stupid when they ask questions.
One time he received a negative review from one of his class students, he just came to me and started justifying that the student wrote the negative review because she wanted to take a revenge of him and it was personal attack and prejudice.
I'm about to defend my Msc in next two semesters, I don't want to quit, but I also don't know how to manage tension with him.

Simply, that person sounds like a complete jerk... and, there's no real way to deal with such people...

You can't fix other people. You can't "not have tension" with someone who is this fragile and automatically creates tension with everyone they interact with.
If you're willing to put up with this, keep your head down and do the best you can to complete all your requirements.
If not, better to move on sooner rather than later.
